# how to sum conditionally?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a following table

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
A1     1      null
A1     2      null
B1     5      null
B2     6      null
M1     1      M
M2     2      M
M3     3      M
J1     1      J
J2     2      J
```

I want to sum Col2 based on Col1. The query will be like following,

```
select Col1, sum (Col2)
group by Col1
```

However, if Col3 has the same letter, I want sum up Col2 for all Col1. So the result table should be like

```
Col1    Col2 
A1      3
B1      5
B2      6
M1      6
M2      6
M3      6
J1      3
J2      3
```

How do I change my query to get above table?

Comment: In your results. Would J2 = 2 and not 3?

Comment: Something is not right with you original question.

Comment: If Col3 has the same letter (not null), I need sum col2 together. So J1 and J2 has the same letter J in col3, the result will be 3 for both J1 and J2.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after comment / update to question. I didn't know a clever way, seems like some others have one though.

```
select * from (
select Col1, SUM(Col2) Col2
from Table
where Col3 is null
group by Col1

union

select mainset.Col1, tmp.Col2
from Table mainset
join 
(
    select Col3, SUM(Col2) Col2
    from Table
    where Col3 is not null
    group by Col3
) tmp on tmp.Col3 = mainset.Col3

where mainset.Col3 is not null
) fullset
order by fullset.Col1
```

Comment: I think you got me worng with Col2 and Col3. I gave a bad example, I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (I named the table #a):

```
    ;WITH col3Sum AS
    (
        SELECT Col3, SUM(Col2) SUM3
        FROM #a
        WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY col3
    ),
        col1Sum AS
    (
        SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) sum1
        FROM #a 
        GROUP BY Col1
    )   
    SELECT c1.Col1, ISNULL(c3.SUM3, c1.sum1) AS Col2
    FROM col1Sum c1
    LEFT JOIN col3Sum c3
        ON c1.Col1 LIKE c3.Col3+'%'
    ORDER BY c1.Col1
```